# i want my posts to show latest first and does but when i edit any post it shows up on top where i want only the posts which were recently added

Tags: python, django

i want my posts to show latest first and does but when i edit any post it shows up on top where i want only the posts which were recently added. Everything works fine but i dont want the edited post to come on top of list

> views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'List/home.html')


def task_list(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    }
    return render(request, 'List/task.html', context)


def edit_task(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    form = TaskForm(instance=post)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('task')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'List/add_task.html', context)
```

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Post(models.Model):
    Task = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='pythons')
    Detail = models.TextField(max_length=100, default='python')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Task
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by this line:

```
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Change it to auto_now_add=True

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can set 'editable=False' for date which means once you set date you can't edit it later so you should also set 'defualt=datetime.datetime.now()' like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    Task = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='pythons')
    Detail = models.TextField(max_length=100, default='python')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime().now,  editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Task
```

Comment: If you use auto_now then it will still get automatically updated every time the row is updated, even if editable=False

Comment: i edit my answer so ithink this might work use datetime.datetime.now() instead of timezone.now()

Comment: yes i  tried to use that and it works but when i update a post  it shows the updated post on top  my order is ordering=['-date']